# SceneKit: Get bones index

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, scenekit

I have a .dae file with a skeleton.

From the skinner baseGeometry proprety, i can get the list of the vertex, and an array of all my bones.
Now i am trying to extract the index bone from : node.skinner.boneIndices

This is my code:

```
- (void)parseIndicesBones:(SCNGeometrySource *)source {


    NSInteger stride = source.dataStride;

    NSInteger offset = source.dataOffset;



    NSInteger componentsPerVector = source.componentsPerVector;

    NSInteger bytesPerVector = componentsPerVector *      source.bytesPerComponent;

    NSInteger vectorCount = source.vectorCount;


    for (NSInteger i=0; i < source.vectorCount; i++) {

         ushort vectorData[componentsPerVector];

         vectorData[0] = 0;
         vectorData[1] = 0;

         NSRange byteRange = NSMakeRange(i*bytesPerVector, bytesPerVector);

         [source.data getBytes:&vectorData range:byteRange];

         NSLog(@"current indices : %u %u", vectorData[0], vectorData[1]);

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: so, what's the question?

Comment: i didn't have success to get the index. In fact i want something like : [indexBone, indexVertex]. I don't know if i parse the data in the right way. The Apple documentation doesn't detail very well this point, and i didn't find any code example.